# No maps visible when downloading something with CartoPackageManager

Tags: carto, .net, maps, mobile, offline

I am facing such problem: while some package is downloading with Carto PackageManager, I can’t see neither other downloaded offline maps nor online maps of any other place.

In other words, if there is some package that is pending or downloading, I **can't use** any map,
I can see only gray background from offline or online vector sources in any location, but as soon as map packages are fully downloaded the map appears in a regular way.

In debugger in both cases no differences, I easily pass over lines (this is full code of mapView initialization) :

```
        MapView = new MapView();
        ConstraintUtils.StretchView(MapContainerView, MapView);

        var baseLayer = new CartoOnlineVectorTileLayer(CartoBaseMapStyle.CartoBasemapStyleDefault);
        baseLayer.Language = MapElementsConstants.LocalizationLanguage;
        MapView.Layers.Add(baseLayer);
        _source = new LocalVectorDataSource(MapView.Options.BaseProjection);
        _layer = new VectorLayer(_source);

        MapView.Layers.Add(_layer);
        MapView.SetZoom(zoom: MapElementsConstants.MapControlHighZoomingCoeff, durationSeconds: 0);
        MapView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Is this feature of CartoSDK or it may be a bug in my application?

All iOS versions (11.2 in particular), Carto NUGET Package version : 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide your entire code? This doesn't seem to be intended behaviour. Once you have downloaded one map package and added `CartoOfflineVectorTileLayer`, you should see the entire map on zoom 0.

Download progress and other events should be available once you attach a `PackageManagerListener`.

If you haven't downloaded any single package, then `CartoOfflineVectorTileLayer` should display a gray background, yes, but `CartoOnlineVectorTileLayer` should still display a map (if you're online)

EDIT:

I created a sample application on Xamarin.iOS with SDK v4.0.2 and everything is working as intended, maps are properly shown. cf application below:

AppDelegate:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    const string LicenseKey = "<YOUR-LICENSE-KEY>";

    public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

    public UINavigationController Controller { get; set; }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        MapView.RegisterLicense(LicenseKey);

        var initial = new MyViewController();
        Controller = new UINavigationController(initial);

        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        Window.RootViewController = Controller;

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MapView ContentView { get; set; }

    public PackageListener Listener { get; set; }

    public CartoPackageManager Manager { get; set; }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        ContentView = new MapView();
        View = ContentView;

        var baseLayer = new CartoOnlineVectorTileLayer(CartoBaseMapStyle.CartoBasemapStyleDefault);
        ContentView.Layers.Add(baseLayer);

        var source = "nutiteq.osm";
        var path = GetDocumentDirectory("com.carto.mappackages.test");
        Manager = new CartoPackageManager(source, path);

        Manager.Start();
        Manager.StartPackageListDownload();

        var offlineLayer = new CartoOfflineVectorTileLayer(Manager, CartoBaseMapStyle.CartoBasemapStyleGray);
        ContentView.Layers.Add(offlineLayer);

        Listener = new PackageListener();
        Manager.PackageManagerListener = Listener;

        Listener.OnPackageListUpdate += Listener_OnPackageListUpdate;
        Listener.OnPackageUpdate += Listener_OnPackageUpdate;
        Listener.OnPackageStatusChange += Listener_OnPackageStatusChange;
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    }

    void Listener_OnPackageListUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("updated package list");
        // Initially downloaded this package
        //Manager.StartPackageDownload("EE");
        // After EE was downloaded, tested with a second download:
        Manager.StartPackageDownload("LV");
    }

    void Listener_OnPackageUpdate(object sender, PackageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("updated package");
    }

    void Listener_OnPackageStatusChange(object sender, PackageStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("status change: " + e.Status.Progress + "%");
    }

    public static string GetDocumentDirectory(string withFolder)
    {
        string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        string path = Path.Combine(documents, withFolder + "/");

        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

Listener convenience class to implement EventHandlers:

```
public class PackageListener : PackageManagerListener
{
    public EventHandler<EventArgs> OnPackageListUpdate;
    public EventHandler<EventArgs> OnPackageListFail;

    public EventHandler<PackageEventArgs> OnPackageCancel;
    public EventHandler<PackageEventArgs> OnPackageUpdate;
    public EventHandler<PackageStatusEventArgs> OnPackageStatusChange;
    public EventHandler<PackageFailedEventArgs> OnPackageFail;

    public PackageListener()
    {

    }

    public override void OnPackageListUpdated ()
    {
        // Called when package list is downloaded.
        // Now you can start downloading packages
        if (OnPackageListUpdate != null) {
            OnPackageListUpdate(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
        }
    }

    public override void OnPackageListFailed ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PackageListener: OnPackageListFailed");
        if (OnPackageListFail != null)
        {
            OnPackageListFail(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public override void OnPackageStatusChanged (string id, int version, PackageStatus status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PackageListener: OnPackageStatusChanged");
        // A portion of package is downloaded. Update your progress bar here.
        // Notice that the view and SDK are in different threads, so data copy id needed
        if (OnPackageStatusChange != null)
        {
            OnPackageStatusChange(this, new PackageStatusEventArgs { Id = id, Version = version, Status = status });
        }
    }

    public override void OnPackageCancelled (string id, int version)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PackageListener: OnPackageCancelled");
        // Called when you called cancel package download
        if (OnPackageCancel != null)
        {
            OnPackageCancel(this, new PackageEventArgs { Id = id, Version = version });
        }
    }

    public override void OnPackageUpdated (string id, int version)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PackageListener: OnPackageUpdated");
        // Called when package is updated
        if (OnPackageUpdate != null)
        {
            OnPackageUpdate(this, new PackageEventArgs { Id = id, Version = version });
        }
    }

    public override void OnPackageFailed (string id, int version, PackageErrorType errorType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PackageListener: OnPackageFailed");

        if (OnPackageFail != null)
        {
            OnPackageFail(this, new PackageFailedEventArgs { Id = id, Version = version, ErrorType = errorType });
        }
    }
}

public class PackageEventArgs
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public class PackageStatusEventArgs : PackageEventArgs
{
    public PackageStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class PackageFailedEventArgs : PackageEventArgs
{
    public PackageErrorType ErrorType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have added details and code. Also I claim that code with OfflineVectorSource is not executed in described situation.

Comment: @OlegKosuakiv see edited answer